# Can a Blazor Parent Component Know How Many Child Components Are Inside It?

Tags: c#, components, blazor, .net-core-3.0, blazor-client-side

I am creating 2 blazor components: `AlertMessage` and `AlertMessageGroup`. `AlertMessageGroup` is designed to contain multiple `AlertMessage` components inside it. I want `AlertMessageGroup` to have display logic based on the number and type of `AlertMessage`s (`AlertMessageType` is an `AlertMessage` parameter, and probably will refer to an enum value).

Is it possible for a parent component (e.g. `AlertMessageGroup`) to know how many children components (e.g. `AlertMessage`) it contains, and to have display logic based on that?

(I'll add that *ideally* I'd like to be able to use a single `AlertMessage` stand-alone, without having to include it inside an `AlertMessageGroup` if I don't want to)

Comment: You can use a CascadingParameter to do this, but I'd advise against it. It's actually counter-intuitive once you start using data binding. Could you just have the component bind to an ICollection | IEnumerable and then just use the Count method to find out how many items you're iterating over?

Comment: Hey @EdCharbeneau - thanks for the suggestion - could you expand on that? When I think of data binding, I'm thinking of binding a parameter value to a control like a text field, so I'm not sure exactly what you mean by binding an IEnumerable to the component itself.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, somehow this got lost in the shuffle. There's now a solid answer for anyone who is looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the most simple solution:

Step 1, create an alert box component:

This is an alert you can use standalone if you wish, per the OP.

```
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2, create an AlertGroup component:

This is a component that can handle an IEnumerable of T alerts.
We'll use TItem to specify that the AlertGroup is generic. It can handle any object we throw at it. Next, we iterate over the `IReadOnlyList<TItem> Items` and render each user defined template inside of an `AlertMessage`.

```
@typeparam TItem

@foreach (var item in Items)
{
    <AlertMessage>
        @AlertTemplate(item)
    </AlertMessage>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TItem> AlertTemplate { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IReadOnlyList<TItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Step 3, put it to use:

Here's the obligatory Counter component. We'll hijack its behavior to render an alert on each count. We'll also capture the total count in a separate Razor output by simply calling `@alerts.Count()`. To the OP, we don't need to track the count internally, since we're feeding TItem from the parent.

Since I'm using a type of `int` in the example, I've defined the built in `Context` parameter as `Value`. If this were an object, the type would likely be inferred and we could use dot notation, ex: `context.Prop`.

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<AlertMessageGroup Items="alerts" Context="Value">
    <AlertTemplate>
        <span>My value is @Value</span>
    </AlertTemplate>
</AlertMessageGroup>

<p>@alerts.Count()</p>

@code {

    List<int> alerts = new List<int>();

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        alerts.Add(currentCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a collection of AlertMessage components in the AlertMessageGroup component, pass a captured Component reference (*this*) to AlertMessage that should add itself to AlertMessageGroup in its OnInitialized life cycle event.

Code snippet for AlertMessage.razor

```
[CascadingParameter]
public AlertMessageGroup ContainerParent { get; set; }


protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    ContainerParent.AddChild(this);
}
```

Code snippet for AlertMessageGroup.razor

// Pass a component reference to the child components

```
 <CascadingValue Value=this>

    </CascadingValue>

    @code {
    // Code to add add the children to the parent...

    }
```

Hope I'm clear...

Comment: I understand the concept and I've tried to implement. The problem is component lifecycle event timing - The AlertMessageGroup parent component is initialized (`OnInitialized()`) and rendered (`OnAfterRender()`) first, so how do I get every AlertMessage child to register itself with the AlertMessageGroup parent in time for the AlertMessageGroup to use that information in its own rendering? (And also how would the AlertMessageGroup parent know when ***all*** the children have added themselves?)